# Unity - how to give objects same material for batching?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im optimizing my game for mobile. For that reason a low amount of batches is important. By using Frame Debug I found out that for some reason the Draw Mesh Node command is performed for every single node eventhough the nodes are static and have the same material as far as I understand. The frame debugger says that the objects cannot be batches because the "Objects have different materials". I dont get why and how to fix that. The nodes are all based on a prefab of them. The only thing that is different between them is their position. Please help

The Frame Debug Window:
[image: The Frame Debug Window]

Prefab for every node:

[image: Prefab of every node]

Example for one of the nodes in game (ONLY their position is different):
[image: Example for one of the nodes in game (ONLY their position is different)]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after 2 days of being sad and watching every graphic performance tutorital on youtube.

Basically I needed to change every .material code to .sharedMaterial because for some to me unknown reason unity creates a copy of the material when using .material, after which each node got its own material. For that reason the performance was so bad. Now it works and my live quality has increased, since everything gets batched, reducing the draw calls from 300 to 10 :)

I hope future readers are helped by this!